# $\frac{\lambda^n}{(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}t^n dt = \frac{1}{\lambda(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-s}ds$

Tags: calculus, integration

In a proof I'm following it says - $$\frac{\lambda^n}{(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}t^n dt$$

$$= \frac{1}{\lambda(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-s}ds$$

I can't see how this is being done.

If I let $s = \lambda t$ I get the following when I sub in

$$= \frac{\lambda^n}{(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-s}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n-1}s^n}ds$$
$$= \frac{1}{\lambda(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-s}s^nds$$

So I have an "extra" with that $s^n$ in the integrand. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
The proof is at the top of page 73 here - https://www.scribd.com/doc/58916126/Stochastic-Solutions-Manual - is this proof incorrect?

Comment: You may get $s^n$ (not $1/s^n$) as 'extra'.

Comment: Agreed, why would you get 1/$s^n$ ? I don't even see how you end up like this since you've just scaled your integration variable

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\lambda^n}{(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}t^n dt = \frac{1}{\lambda(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n d(\lambda t)$$

So if you substitute $s= \lambda t$, we will have

$$\frac{\lambda^n}{(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}t^n dt = \frac{1}{\lambda(n - 1)!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-s}s^n ds$$

Then we need to integrate by parts. Or use we know about [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function): 
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-s}s^n ds = \Gamma(n+1)= n!$$

Comment: Look at the top of page 73 here - https://www.scribd.com/doc/58916126/Stochastic-Solutions-Manual

Comment: @sonicboom I've edited. I think the first equation in your question is not true

Answer (score 2):

The "equality" which you try to prove is not an real equality. Take $\lambda=1$ then left side is equal to 1, but right side is equal to $1/(n-1)!$ and they are not equal in genreal.